# How the MVC patterns works in ZKoss

Tags: templates, jakarta-ee, zk

i'm trying my hands around the zkoss library and it's kinda cool.I just happen to have learnt
the MVC pattern through zend framework and it's like i'm kind of lost a bit.
i have a couple of question that i would like somebody to shed some light over.

**1**  Do we have the concept of page as index page (a file) login page (another file) ?

**2** Do we have the concept of layout as decorator patterns where i have a layout and it's used to display different view (much like zf and symfony in php) ?

i think i've read somewhere about the templating with annotations but still that doesn't the questions of if there is page per view or something else (question 1)

thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ZK, there's a concept named composition, I'm not sure if this is what you want:
[ZK Templating by Composition](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Templating/Composition)

Answer (score 1):

For question one, simple answer is "Yes". You have the option to jump from one page to another page. However, ZK is an Ajax framework that you can also easily write a one-page application without problem. E.g., you can popup a login dialog on a click of button without change the page at all. It is your option.